# Switch Power BI data sources from Excel to Azure analysis services

Tags: azure, ssas, powerbi, azure-analysis-services

Right now I have created power bi dashboard (using power bi desktop) which retrieves data from excel file. Later on I will replicate the same data model to Azure analysis services tabular model.

Is it possible to switch my power bi dashboard's data source to azure analysis service seamlessly?. What I mean is that I don't have to do major rework on my dashboard (re-create the visualization again, etc). How do I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me the hard fact is that it may not be seamless. There may be possibility of minimizing some extra work though but you need to answer few questions yourself and then decide:-

1. Do you plan to use SSAS Tabular in Power BI using live connection or import mode? (I assume you are probably having this cube as on-premise)
2. Is the data layout in the excel (understand it like flattened data) going to be same as in SSAS Tabular?

One option worth considering would be to have the SSAS Tabular cube readily loaded using the data from the excel and you start off the development of Power BI. That way source changes in Power BI will not be an issue going forward.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Hi Rupesh. to answer your question :
1. We will use live connection to Azure Analysis Services 
2. Yes the SSAS tabular model will have similar layout with the excel file (flattened data)

Comment: Just to clarify, current condition is that we already have functional power bi dashboard using the excel file as data source.

Since you said to start off power bi development once the tabular cube is loaded with data, Am I correct to say that in my current condition I will have to re-create all the visualization if I switch the data source to Azure analysis services tabular cube?

Comment: First, you can copy one visual from a PBIX page to another; however, you won't be able to do so from one file to another. Second, when you create a Power BI report with SSAS Tabular as a source and live connection in place, the data and relationships tab will be inaccessible. So, right now with excel as source you have relationships, etc. in the PBIX file, how will these be managed when you "switch" to SSAS Tabular? That was the reason i have suggested to use SSAS Tabular as source with live connection from the start, else re-create the visual !!